# Typing with Applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

Is it possible to have my mac type for you with applescript? 
What I want is this: when compiled, this applescript will type a phrase, then press enter. Is there any code simulating the pressing of keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `keystroke` command will work for you.

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "A phrase" & return & "Another phrase"
```

If you want a specific application to do the typing, just do something along these lines:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "TextEdit" to keystroke "A phrase" & return & "Another phrase"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, look at keystroke and key down in System Events > Processes Suite, though you have to turn on Universal Access