# Getting Mac OS Speakable Items to simulate a keystroke to an application

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm trying to configure my Mac so that I can use my voice to control page turning (e.g. while exercising).

Based on a combination of http://alvinalexander.com/apple/mac-voice-speech-recognition-software-commands-custom and [Typing with Applescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661348/typing-with-applescript) I created a file called `Next Page.scpt` in the directory of speakable items with the contents:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Kindle" to keystroke " "
```

The software is recognizing my "Next Page" voice prompt, as it echo's back that command name, but I'm not getting the effect of typing a space. Nothing is apparently happening and I have no idea how to debug. Prior to issuing this command, I've switched to Kindle itself.

As an aside, the rest of the files in the speakable events directory are XML files and not simple applescript files. I have not tried figuring out and adopting the XML format.

Comment: The SPACE-Key has the key code 49, please see adamh's edited answer. (tell application "System Events" to key code 49)

Comment: …and when you test it in AppleScript-Editor don't use CMD-R to run the script because that pops up the spotlight search bar (CMD & SPACE key pressed together) lol

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
tell application "Kindle"
   activate
   tell application "System Events" to keystroke " "
end tell
```

or sometimes *keystroke* can be effectively replaced with *key code*, in your case SPACE would be: `key code 49`

List of other key codes [here](http://rhinoceros.hubpages.com/hub/AppleScript-Key-Code-List)

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and the `key code 51` variation, but still nothing. Is there any reasonably easy way to debug what's going on?

Comment: Maybe try it with TextEdit (or the like) first, as you should see what is typed in the window. Also is there another way to next page in the Kindle app? Perhaps a menu or button, then you could try some ui scripting instead.

Comment: @adamh the space key has the code 49 (I use ManyTrick's free "Key Codes" app)

Comment: my bad, 51 is delete! lesson: don't write S.O. answers with a 3 year old jumping on you.

Comment: Sure, good idea: @Peter Alfvin you also might want to re-try with key code 49 as digimonk points out. I have edited my answer to reflect.

Comment: @DigiMonk and @Adamh - +1 and thank you. I've been able to get the script to run fine in the AppleEditor (I suspect multiple variants will work and perhaps even my original). But it still doesn't work in the Speakable Items folder. I'm still concerned that the existing items are all XML, although http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760633/how-do-i-get-applescript-to-respond-to-what-i-say/16764040#16764040 and other posts suggest you  can use apple script files instead (I've tread both text and `.scpt` versions).

Comment: Just found http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14380 Haven't tried it yet, but looks very encouraging.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Speakable Items capability to define the keyboard commands, as follows (extracted from http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14380):

[image]

This same document also discusses how to create commands for other functions, including running scripts.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, using down arrow:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Kindle" to key code 125
```

(key code 124, which is right arrow, should also work; back (back a page) could be up arrow (key code 126) or left arrow (123)